# javascript - disappearing dynamically created textbox's value when add another one

Tags: javascript

with this code,i dynamically create textbox,but when i fill sometext in textbox and then again press add butten,first textbox's value get disappeard.

```js
<script>
  function add()
{
    document.getElementById("place").innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="bimename">';

}</script>
<div id="place"></div><input type="button" onClick="add();" value="add">
```

Comment: You're always generating the textbox in the same `div#place` (so the previous textbox is overwritten). Instead, on click, you would need to create another placeholder dynamically and add another textbox to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create real `<input>` elements.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5zrsfvg/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="add" /><div id="place"></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('input[value="add"]').onclick = function add() {
    var newElem = document.createElement('input');
    newElem.type = 'text';
    newElem.name = 'bimename';
    document.getElementById('place').appendChild(newElem);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code:

```js
function add()
{
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "text";
   input.name = "bimename";
   document.getElementById("place").appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div id="place"></div><input type="button" onClick="add();" value="add">
```